# continuity of series of powers of cosine

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, trigonometric-series

I'm trying to understand the continuity of 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos^n(nx)}{n^{3/2}}.$$
I believe these series converge and it can be proved by comparison test.
I also figured that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \cos^n(nx)$$ is discontinuous at $x=\frac{\pi k}{n}$ where $k$ is an integer.
My intuition tells me that the series should be discontinuous at the same $x$. However, I don't know how to prove or disaprove this.

Comment: @metamorphy yes. I just found the theorem in Rudin's book that states that if $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $E$ and if $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly, then $f$ is uniform. The series above converge uniformly by M-test.

Comment: @metamorphy thank you very much. How would one prove this using epsilon delta though?

Comment: I don't cut firewood with a jigsaw. Those who do may reproduce the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem) of the theorem.